# SQL : select distinct from two columns and min from the third colum

Tags: sql

My data set looks like this

| customer | product | purchase-date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vik | office | 21-04-2022 |
| vik | office2 | 21-02-2021 |
| vik | office | 21-01-2021 |
| vik | office2 | 21-02-2023 |
| abc | office | 1-02-2022 |
| abc | office | 1-02-2021 |

I want to run a SQL query that returns this output

| customer | product | purchase-date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vik | office | 21-01-2021 |
| vik | office2 | 21-02-2021 |
| abc | office | 1-02-2021 |

I effectively want to use select distinct on customer and product and find the min purchase date for that distinct combination, I have tried select statements, tried partitions but the output isn't returned as expected.

When I use partitions, the minimum date from the entire column gets picked up as opposed to min within each distinct customer & product combination.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
with data as 
(
    select 
        *, 
        row_number() over (partition by customer order by purchase-date) as rownum
    from 
        table
)
select * 
from data 
where rownum = 1
```

This is supposed to return a rownum column and then I run a query with a `where` clause `rownum = 1`, but when I do that it picks up the lowest value of `purchase-date` and not lowest in each

Comment: What's your database system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select distinct` does not allow calculations such as minimum, but `GROUP BY` can, while it also creates distinct combinations:

```
SELECT 
    customer, product, MIN(purchase-date) as purchase-date
FROM t
GROUP BY
    customer, product
```

Put the columns that you want as the distinct items under the group by clause, and put those plus the MIN or MAX (or SUM COUNT etc.) in the select clause.

To use `row_number()` to achieve the equivalent, you need to specify all the columns that you need to be "distinct" in the `partition by` element

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM (
    SELECT 
         customer, product, purchase-date
       , row_number() over(partition by customer, product 
                           order by purchase-date ASC) as rn
    FROM t
     ) d
WHERE rn = 1
```

Row numbering (re)commences at 1 for each distinct combination of customer, product, and the specific row that will get row 1 is the row with the earliest date (or it could be equal earliest). Only 1 row for each partition can get the row number 1.

---

**Tests:**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  customer VARCHAR(50),
  product VARCHAR(50),
  purchase_date DATE
);
 
INSERT INTO t (customer, product, purchase_date)
VALUES
  ('vik', 'office', '2022-04-21'),
  ('vik', 'office2', '2021-02-21'),
  ('vik', 'office', '2021-01-21'),
  ('vik', 'office2', '2023-02-21'),
  ('abc', 'office', '2022-02-01'),
  ('abc', 'office', '2021-02-01');

SELECT 
    customer, product, MIN(purchase_date) as purchase_date
FROM t
GROUP BY
    customer, product
```

| customer | product | purchase_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | office | 2021-02-01 |
| vik | office | 2021-01-21 |
| vik | office2 | 2021-02-21 |

```
SELECT 
     *
FROM (
    SELECT 
         customer, product, purchase_date
       , row_number() over(partition by customer, product 
                           order by purchase_date ASC) as rn
    FROM t
     ) d
WHERE rn = 1
```

| customer | product | purchase_date | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | office | 2021-02-01 | 1 |
| vik | office | 2021-01-21 | 1 |
| vik | office2 | 2021-02-21 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5_wX4cHP)

Comment: when I do that, the output will have the lowest purchase date across all rows that are returned and not lowest per group.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. To get the lowest date for all rows would be to have no group by clause at all i..e `select min(date) from t`

Comment: Please now re-look at the answer, and trial the queries using the fiddle. You need to trust that GROUP BY produces the equivalent of "select distinct" BUT ALSO can do so much more!

Comment: What I meant was I get the distinct records from the group by but the purchase date value is showing as 2021-01-21 for all the rows

Comment: Thanks Paul, let me try again with my dataset and using the fiddle queries  as a reference

Comment: NOT true in my results using the data you provided. Please refresh the answer if you can't see the actual query results and/or look here https://dbfiddle.uk/5_wX4cHP

Comment: I had problems with my dataset and hence the issues I was seeing all sorted now thanks Paul